# linq query to xml with variable having clause

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq

Trying to create linq query from following xml.

```
<root>
  <mileage value="100">
  </mileage>
  <mileage value="75">
  </mileage>
  <mileage value="60">
  </mileage>
   <mileage value="50">
  </mileage>
</root>
```

The output needs to iterate xml tree getting all mileage values in mileage node and count each total when greater than or equal to 50, greater than or equal to 75 and greater than or equal to 100. So the output would be:

```
<root>
      <mileage value="100" count="1"/>
      <mileage value="75" count="2"/>
      <mileage value="50" count="4"/>
</root>
```

Not sure where to begin

Comment: thank you for bringing that to my attention the numbers should be value of 50 should be 4, value of 75 should be 3(NOT 2) and value of 100 should be 1.  So the 75 was off by one.

Comment: Actually, I think, I was completely confused when I wrote my comment ;-) All the values are correct, there are two entries with 75 or greater: 75 and 100. So, the value 2 is correct.

Comment: any luck on code to produce values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a piece of code that does exactly what you want. You should add error handling and consider the cases where not all the attributes are present or they are not what you expect (mileage value is not an int for example).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XElement result = new XElement("root");
        int[] groupValues = { 100, 75, 50 };

        string xml = "<root><mileage value=\"100\"></mileage><mileage value=\"75\"></mileage><mileage value=\"60\"></mileage><mileage value=\"50\"></mileage></root>";
        XElement element = XElement.Parse(xml);

        foreach (int groupValue in groupValues)
        {
            var newGroup = new XElement("mileage");
            newGroup.Add(new XAttribute("value", groupValue));
            newGroup.Add(new XAttribute("count", element.Elements("mileage").Count(m => int.Parse(m.Attribute("value").Value) >= groupValue)));

            result.Add(newGroup);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: wow, thanks alot, exactly what i needed alfonso can you calrify this:m => int.Parse(m.Attribute("value").Value) >= groupValue)

Comment: You're welcome! m is a mileage element in your current xml. That line retrieves the "value" attribute of that node, which is a string, then it parses it into an integer. So the element is only counted if the "value" attribute is greater or equal than groupValue which is the value for the group (100, 75 or 50).